# Recursion - math formula, write a program

Tags: c, recursion, recurrence

I need to implement this math formula in C:

[image]

I wrote a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c(int n, int k)
{
    if(k == 0)
        return n;
    if(c(n,k-1) % 2 == 0)
        return c(n,k-1)/2;
    if(c(n,k-1) % 2 != 0)
        return c(n,k-1) * 3 + 1;
}

int main()
{

    printf("%d", c(3,8));

    return 0;
}
```

But I'm wondering if it was all about it? Does it work like it should? I must admit I have some troubles with calculating it on a paper ...

Comment: if your expression is correct, yes it should work.

Comment: You should not make the same recursive call multiple times. It will make the runtime exponential instead of linear.

Comment: @interjay: Interesting point. So it should look more like this: http://pastie.org/private/bqcyl9qgylfpjsssyukhba?

Comment: @striving_coder: but the second version (from pastie) is valid too, right?

Comment: @striving_coder That's incorrect. Multiple identical recursive calls will cause repeated calls. Maybe a compiler can be smart enough to notice that the function is pure and has no side effects and therefore there is no need for multiple calls, but most won't (GCC doesn't optimize to one call here). This isn't about iteration vs. recursion, but about a single recursive call vs. multiple calls.

Comment: @interjay: Deleted my previous comment, since it was misunderstanding on my part. You're right, multiple recursive calls are counter-effective.

Comment: @BrianBrown: Yep, both versions are correct, the one from pastie being more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my calculation, the correct answer for n=3, k=8 should be 4, so your example should give you that. The program itself looks correct.

Update:

Here is how I do it on paper:

We're starting from c(0) - since in this case the value is known in any case:

```
c(0)=n=3
```

And go up, on each step choosing the calculation method based on evenness of the c(k-1):

```
c(1)=c(0)*3+1=10
c(2)=c(1)/2=5
c(3)=c(2)*3+1=16
c(4)=c(3)/2=8
c(5)=c(4)/2=4
c(6)=c(5)/2=2
c(7)=c(6)/2=1
c(8)=c(7)*3+1=4
```

Comment: Could you be so kind and write how did you calculate it, step-by-step manually? Yes, for 3 and 8, my program gives me 4, so it seems to be correct.